# how to download to specific folder using selenium webdriver in firefox

Tags: java, selenium

I have used below code to download to specific path:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();          
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);          
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", PATH To Download);
```

`profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);`

But after clicking on download button in application it throws error:
File not found
Firefox can't find the file at https:///site/conversion/zipDowload?docIds=95760,.
    Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
    Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.
Please help to resolve this.

Comment: It seems you are getting download error. Are you able to download that particular file manually?

Comment: Its not throwing error message now (might be intermittent issue). Its opening the pop-up with options 'Open with', 'Save File'. Open with is selected by default. How to select Save file and click on OK button.